# Code to generate a hash based on all public getters from an Object - Java

Tags: java, reflection

I'd a method that should read all public methods (including superclass) and for each non-null attribute store it´s hashCode.

```
private static String reflect(Object o) {
    StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        for (Method m : o.getClass().getMethods()) {
            if (m.getName().startsWith("get") || m.getName().startsWith("is")) {
                Object result = m.invoke(o, new Object[]{});
                key.append(result != null ? result.hashCode() : "-");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return key.toString();
}
```

Is this code Ok or I´ve forgetting something important in relation to my needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only obvious thing I can see is that if you're using the hashcodes to identify changes in the object, you should know that the [order of methods returned by getMethods()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods()) is "not in any particular order", so there is no guarantee that they'll be returned in the same order in another JVM, or even from call to call.